# Jquery - Unterminated String Constant

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a page with jquery on it. It works fine in Firefox, Chrome etc but if I load it in IE, none of the Jquery functions run, and IE's script debugger shows:

---

### Error

A Runtime Error has occurred.
Do you wish to Debug?

Line: 269

### Error: Unterminated string constant

### Yes   No

The line in question is in my (unmodified) jquery.js that is causing the error is

style.left = ret || 0;

It also shows:

---

### Error

A Runtime Error has occurred.
Do you wish to Debug?

Line: 835

### Error: Invalid argument.

### Yes   No

With the line in question being:

ret = style.pixelLeft + "px";

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Seems I may have been looking in the wrong place for the error. If I take this out, it works:

```
    $(".middlebox").children("p").hide();
    $(".middlebox").addClass("middlebox_closed", "fast");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is not necessarily in the jQuery code, but the argument value being passed as a parameter into a function in jQuery *i.e.* the step before.

**EDIT:**

This line is incorrect

```
$(".middlebox").addClass("middlebox_closed", "fast");
```

[`addClass()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/addClass) does not take 2 arguments, just one which is a string for the class that you wish to add. Change it to

```
$(".middlebox").addClass("middlebox_closed");
```

and it will work. Or maybe  you wanted to add 2 classes, in which case this will work too

```
$(".middlebox").addClass("middlebox_closed").addClass("fast");
// or this for brevity
$(".middlebox").addClass("middlebox_closed fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. (maybe) Try using style.left instead of pixelLeft
   Also check that style is initialised properly.
2. What are you trying to achieve by this line? style.left = ret || 0;
   Maybe you wanted something like style.left = parseInt(ret)